# How to code an Android Volley JSONArrayRequest PUT returning JSON Object

Tags: android-volley

I am using android volley JSONArrayRequest with PUT to create a new version of an item on my remote server using the following code

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            ( Request.Method.PUT
            , ServerItemUpdateUrl + RemoteId + "/" + VersionNumber
            , jsonArray
            , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
                    {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Comms Success :" + response.toString());
                    }
                }
            , new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Comms Error :" + error.toString());
                    }
                 }
            )
            {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() 
                {
                return ServerItemContentType ;
                }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
                {
                Map<String, String>
                        params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Authorization", AuthorizationPrefix + token);
                params.put("Content-Type", ServerItemContentType);
                return params;
                }
            };

        ServerHttpRequestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

However the server returns a JSON object (basically confirming where the data has been put) and this causes a com.android.volley.ParseError with org.json.JSONException, perhaps not surprisingly as it is expecting a JSON array to be returned. I have tried setting the listener to null and this does not remove the error.

Please can someone tell me how I can change Response.Listener to accept a JSON Object?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use the code below in order to override the default Array parsing response behaviour and allow it to parse an object. This code is inserted inside the anonymous inner class shown in the OP, i.e. after "return params;}"

```
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse response)
                    {
                    try {
                        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        Log.i(TAG, "Comms Response " + jsonString);
                        return Response.success(new JSONArray("["+jsonString+"]"), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                        }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                        {
                        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                        }
                    catch (JSONException je) {
                        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
                        }
                    };
```

Note the enclosing "[" and "]" which effectively translate the string from a representation of a json object to one representing a json array with a single element containing the returned json object.

Tested and working.